# Oracle Missing Comma

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have been working at this for hours and I cannot figure out what is wrong...

I have written this code

```
INSERT INTO Agents (ID,Name,Phone,Cert_Level,Join_Date) VALUES (1,’Chris’,’317-9578’,1,’01-NOV-91’);
```

and I get the same missing comma error over and over and I cannot find the problem PLEASE HELP ME

here is the database and I have confirmed that it was created correctly

Agents :

```
ID Int Primary key
Name Char(10) Not Null
Phone Char(9) Not Null
Cert_Level Int Restricted to values 1-10
Join_Date Date
```

Comment: replace angular quote with '

Comment: :-) welcome to the subtleties of oracle . `"` is much different from `'` and this `\`` is different  also

Comment: How exactly do I replace the quotes

Comment: I hate everything that is Oracle. Thanks for the help Coffee and Rajesh.

Comment: When you learn it, you would be in love with it :-) Anyway, apart from the quotes, there are many things wrong in your SQL. See my answer.

Comment: Run notepad.  Type a `'` (single quote) and then copy/paste with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below code as you are different quotes, replace ’ to ' .

```
 INSERT INTO Agents (ID,Name,Phone,Cert_Level,Join_Date) VALUES (1,'Chris','317-9578',1,'01-NOV-91');
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Your string literals are delimited with unicode character Right single quotation mark (u+2019)
instead of Apostrophe (' u+0027).
You can try typing the apostrophes.

```
’Chris’
```

vs

```
'Chris'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using a basic text editor and didn't realize that because it was such a subtle difference in the oracle window.

Comment: programming languages have strict rules to parse the source code. you'll have to get used to subtleties like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Even after you correct your angular quotes with single quotes, you will still be in trouble because of the date literal.

The `join_date` is a `DATE` data type column, so this `'01-NOV-91'` is wrong. Since, in Oracle anything between single quotes is considered string. You need to use `TO_DATE` to convert it into DATE with proper format mask.

For example : `TO_DATE('01-NOV-91', 'DD-MON-RR')`

Since you have a two digit year, and we all have seen the Y2K bug, I have user `RR` format. Better use `YYYY` for year.